# Jwt error:Jwt must be provided,How Can I provide jwt?

Tags: express, authentication, post, mern

I'm trying to use a request to make role authorization by there's an error in jwt
it tells me that jwt must be provided and here's my my userRoute.js where the routes are configured:

```
    router.post("/get-user-info-by-id", authMiddleware, async (req,res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.userId });
    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "User does not exist", success: false });
    } else {
      res.status(200).send({
        success: true,
        data: {
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
        },
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .send({ message: "Error getting user info", success: false, error });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and this is my authMiddleware.js where I must provide the jwt :

```
 const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
     //const t =req.headers["authorization"];
    //const token=String(t).split(" ");
    const token = req.headers["authorization"]?.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(401).send({
          message: "Auth failed !",
          success: false,
        });
      } else {
        req.body.userId = decoded._id;
        next();
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    return res.status(401).send({
      message: "Auth failed",
      success: false,
    });
  }
};
```

this is the login route in userRoute.js:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let token = "";
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "User does not exist", success: false });
    }
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .send({ message: "Password is incorrect ", success: false });
    } else {
      token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "1d",
      });
    }
    if (user && isMatch) {
      res
        .status(200)
        .send({
          message: "Login successful",
          success: true,
          token,
          data: token,
        });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    res
      .status(500)
      .send({ message: "Error logging in ", success: false, error });
  }
});
```

the login works correctly with no problem

Comment: The _client_ that makes the request must provide the JWT in the `Authorization: Bearer <JWT>` header. Before it can do so, it must log in to your server and _receive_ a JWT. Can you share your code for the `/login` route?

Comment: I modified the post you can see  the /login route

Comment: That looks OK. So the client must take the token from the response to the `POST /login` request and put it in the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header in the subsequent `POST /get-user-info-by-id` request.

Comment: how do I send the token from the login  in the authorization ?

Comment: You need client-side Javascript code takes extracts the `token` from the JSON response to the `POST /login` request and injects an `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header into the subsequent `POST /get-user-info-by-id` request.

Comment: I fixed the error now it tells me jwt was expired